# What word best describes the start and stop points of a trip/journey, separating the notion of the routes between them?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to find a precise, succinct, and preferably single word term to describe only the start and stop points of a trip and should be very clear that it does not entail the many routes between them.

For example,

- (x,y and x,y) is the {missing term}
- and here are the possible routes between them.

Comment: Do you want something more elegant than _endpoints_?

Comment: Not bad but the "end" in endpoints might be a bit off-putting for the start point. I was really hoping for something crystal clear.

Comment: 'Stop[ping]-off points' [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stop-off-point)] seems a better fit here than at the 'duplicate'.